# Construcción de listas anidadas

Tags: python, lista, agrupación

Tengo el siguiente código que me entrega como resultado una lista de listas.

```
miLista = [[32, 64, 120, 256],[250, 980]]
nuevaLista = [] 

for e in miLista:
    for i in range(len(e)):
        a = i+2
        x = [i//a for i in e]
        nuevaLista.append(x)

print(nuevaLista)
```

Resultado que obtengo:

> [[16, 32, 60, 128], [10, 21, 40, 85], [8, 16, 30, 64], [6, 12, 24, 51], [125, 490], [83, 326]]

Sin embargo, necesito agruparla de otra forma:

Resultado deseado:

> [[16, 32, 60, 128, 10, 21, 40, 85, 8, 16, 30, 64, 6, 12, 24, 51],[125, 490, 83, 326]]

He estado intentando nuevo código para lo anterior:

```
miLista = [[32, 64, 120, 256],[250, 980]]
x = [[(i+2) for i in e for i in range(len(e))] for e in miLista]
```

me agrupa el resultado como necesito pero me da esto:

> [[2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 2, 3]]

¿Cómo lo puedo arreglar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas creando la sublista `x` dentro del segundo `for`, por lo que vreas una lista por cada elemento de cada sublista de `miLista`. Para el resultado que deseas debes crearla al inicio del mismo, no dentro de el. Una forma "expandida" sería:

```
mi_lista = [[32, 64, 120, 256], [250, 980]]
nueva_lista = [] 

for e in mi_lista:
    aux = []
    for i in range(len(e)):
        a = i + 2
        for n in e:
            aux.append(n // a)
    nueva_lista.append(aux)

print(nueva_lista)
```

Si quieres usar *list comprehension* sería:

```
nueva_lista = [[n // (i + 2) for n in e for i in range(len(e))] for e in mi_lista]
```

> ```
> >>> nueva_lista
> [
>  [16, 10, 8, 6, 32, 21, 16, 12, 60, 40, 30, 24, 128, 85, 64, 51],
>  [125, 83, 490, 326]
> ]
> ```

En tu intento usando list comprehension has estado muy cerca , pero no debes usar la misma variable para los dos ciclos anidados, `for i in range(len(e)` y `for i in e`. Esto causa que la variable `i` generada por `for i in range(len(e)` solape a la generada por `for i in e`.